# Siebel table apply doesn't affect the database

Tags: sql, oracle, siebel

In Siebel Tools, I added a new column to a table. After applying and compiling the changes, the UI App shows a SQL error (SBL-DBC-00105), and when running a simple Select query directly to the database I found that the new column isn't added to the table.

```
Error message    
    
We detected an error that may have occurred for one of the following reasons:
 
An error occurred while executing an SQL statement. Please continue 
or ask the system administrator to check the application configuration 
if the problem persists. (SBL-DBC-00105)
```

I double checked the ODBC data source and DB credentials, all good.

Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: can you please provide the complete error message as text

Comment: If you've got access to Oracle support then document 478651.1 might give you some clues. But you probably need to capture the SQL it's issuing, probably from a log file. There might be something obvious in how you defined the new column though (e.g. trying to create a Boolean, which Oracle doesn't support (yet)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Apply/DDL your new changes.

Assuming you are using Siebel Tools IP15. Login to server tools and search for your newly updated table in Tools.

Click on Apply/DDL button
[image]

Then choose option "Apply":

[image]

Comment: Your answer looks good. Clicking numbered links - instead of looking at attached images - makes reading a little bit troublesome. Could you be so kind, as to edit your answer and attach images using the post editor?

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying your DB changes to the same database which hosts your development reposoitory? In case you are applying to some other environment (e.g. from Development Tools to Test database) apply would not work as Siebel Tools are comparing physical schema with logical schema and would find no differeneces if your repository has no new column definition.

That means you have to migrate your changes from DEV repository to TEST before applying table changes. Or use DDL generation instead of applying.